# How to change the background color of the HTML5 video control bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-video

I have recently added a video on our website using the tag below:

```
<video autoplay>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="100%">
</video>
```

The video display like below:

[image]

I now which to change the background color of the control bar indicated above. I have searched but have not found something so far. Appreciate assistance

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics) you can find an answer to your question.